# Django rest framework add data to serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add data to my serializer.  What I have is a `Game` model and a `Game` can have multiple `Match` models attached to it.  The thing is, the `Game` model doesn't know about this relationship.  The relationship is on the `Match` model as a foreign key to the `Game`.

However, there are times when I am getting a `Game` I want to include the `Match` models with them.  Here is my model for a `Game`:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Game(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.created_at:
            self.created_at = timezone.now()
        self.updated_at = timezone.now()
        return super(Analysis, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "games"
```

And my `Match` model:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from games.models import Game

class Match(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.created_at:
            self.created_at = timezone.now()
        self.updated_at = timezone.now()
        return super(Match, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "matches"
```

And my `GameSerializer`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from games.models import Game
from games.serializers import GameSerializer

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

I am assuming that I need to tweak my `GameSerializer` to make this work correctly and send down the related data.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the match field to your GameSerializer, and handle the save yourself.

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    matches = MatchSerializer(many=True, source='match_set')

    def save(self):
        matches = self.validated_data.get('matches', [])
        game = super(GameSerializer, self).save()
        for match in matches:
            match['game'] = game
            Match.objects.create(**match)
```

Add matches to your fields. In the validated_data of the serializer, `matches` will be a list of validated datas from MatchSerializer. So you can go ahead and create the Match object directly in your GameSerializer save.

Ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Or if your usecase involves matches sending already existing Match object and you will only need to send the ids in your data, then use this:

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    matches = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(Match))

    def save(self):
        matches = self.validated_data.get('matches')
        game = super(GameSerializer, self).save()
        for match in matches:
            match.game = game
            match.save()
```

Comment: This doesn't work since `matches` is not present on the `Game` model.

Comment: @Sethen it is not mandatory that all serializer fields should be present in the model. There can be extra fields in a model serializer that can be used for cases like these

Comment: Then why does DRF throw an error when attempting to use your code above?

Comment: @Sethen Can you post the traceback?

Comment: `AttributeError at /game/e4da124ef1e94fff9a6b0fbc36c39f1c/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field matches on serializer GameSerializer.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the Game instance.
Original exception text was: Game object has no attribute 'matches'.`

Comment: Did you add `matches` to your serializer fields?

Comment: Affirmative comrade.

Comment: @Sethen have you overridden the `to_representation` method of the serializer? If not, try adding `source='match_set'` to the `matches` serializer field declaration. Else override to_representation to customize your response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172713/discussion-between-aswin-murugesh-and-sethen).

Comment: You got it -- it was actually adding `source='match_set'` that made it work.  Bravo!

Comment: You should take off the `def to_representation` that actually just makes it return the `id` in the JSON response.

Comment: Removed it.. I had added it just for your reference about the method